# iPhone does not show up on iPhoto anymore

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, photos.app, photos

Since the update to iOS5 my iPhone 3GS does not show up as a device on iPhoto anymore. Before that, iPhoto was working without any hitch. I'm currently using the following:

- MacBook Pro 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5, 4 GB, Mac OS X 10.7.2
- iPhoto '09 Version 8.1.2 (424)
- iPhone 3GS, with IOS 5
- iTunes 10.5 (141) 64-bit

Is there some way to recover so that I can import photos on iPhoto again, or is the software not compatible anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... Apparently, restarting the computer (with the applications not reopening) seemed to get iPhoto to work again.

I hope there are other ways of doing this.

Comment: Image Capture Extension or PTPCamera is used when synching in iPhoto. If any of those have crashed, maybe starting them again might get iPhoto to work again.

Answer (score 1):

In iPhoto>preferences>general you're able to choose what happens when a camera connects to your Mac.  If you choose Iphoto, your iPhone should appear as you want it to.

I discovered this in reverse.  When I first got my iPhone, iPhoto automatically launched and by unchecking this feature in Iphoto, it stopped.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This has been bugging me for a bit. I already had the above it just stopped working. I went into preferences as above and changed it to open something else when a camera (phone) was attached. There's a couple of options in there I don't remember them now. I plugged the phone in and it launched that app ok. So I went back in and changed it to iPhoto again, took the phone off then reconnected and booshka - back to normal. See if that works...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings.app, then select General. Scroll down to "Passcode Lock". Tap it, enter your passcode, and then proceed to turn passcode lock off.